# How can I get the ID of a item from a DropDownList in WebForms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, dropdown

I have `dropdownlist` with some items in it and I'm inserting the items by pulling the data from a `SQLServer` database. So I want to edit a item depending on what item is selected at the moment. The idea I have is to get the ID of the specific item that is selected by clicking on a button, how can I do that in `WebForms`?

> .ASPX Code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEvento" name="1" class="form-control" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnEdit_EventType"  CssClass="editButton"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: ddlEvento.SelectedItem.Value would give you value associated with the selected item.

Comment: Want it in script or back-end code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To get selected item's value field in script**

$('#MainContent_ddlEvento').val()  /*replace MainContent with your ContentPlaceHolderID*/

or

var e = document.getElementById("ddlEvento");
var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

**To get selected item's value field in back-end code**

ddlEvento.SelectedValue